# Angular Form is not valid even after all form fields are valid

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-test

I m trying to solve one **Angular form validation** *Hands on*, for that i made the below form, this form is passing all the test cases except one, looks like the problem is with testing file(app.component.spec.ts) that is **readable only** [working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f1be3c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) of the handson shows form status as **VALID.** but it fails testing

*I am stuck with this handson form last two days.**Your help is cordially appreciated**.*

-------------------[read only]app.component.spec.ts----------

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl, AbstractControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { asNativeElements, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));

  // it('should create the component', () => {
  //   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  // });

  it('form should be invalid when empty', () => {
    expect(component.contactForm.invalid).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('form should be valid on entering required fields', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges(); // ngOninit()
    component.name.setValue('david');
    component.phone.setValue('9999999999');

    expect(component.contactForm.valid).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('#name', () => {
    let name: AbstractControl;

    beforeEach(() => {
      name = component.contactForm.controls['name'];
    });

    it('should be invalid if empty', () => {
      expect(name.invalid).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should be a "required" field', () => {
      expect(name.errors['required']).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should be valid if some value is present', fakeAsync(() => {
      name.setValue('david');
      expect(name.valid).toBeTruthy();
    }));
  });

  describe('#phone', () => {
    let phone: AbstractControl;
    beforeEach(() => {
      phone = component.contactForm.controls['phone'];
    });

    it('should be invalid if empty', () => {
      expect(phone.invalid).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should have "required" validation', () => {
      expect(phone.errors['required']).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should accept only numbers(pattern validation)', () => {
      phone.setValue('abc');
      expect(phone.errors['pattern']).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should have 10 digits(minlength & maxlength validation)', () => {
      phone.setValue('123');
      expect(phone.errors['minlength']).toBeTruthy();
      phone.setValue('12333333333');
      expect(phone.errors['maxlength']).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });

  describe('#address - zip', () => {
    let address;
    let zip;
    beforeEach(() => {
      address = component.contactForm.controls['address'] as FormGroup ;
      zip = address.controls['zip'] ;
      fixture.detectChanges(); // ngOnInit()
    });
    it('should be a number', fakeAsync(() => {
      zip.setValue('abc');
      expect(zip.errors['pattern']).toBeTruthy();
      zip.setValue('123456');
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(zip.valid).toBeTruthy();
    }));
    it('should have 6 digits exactly', () => {
      // enter 3 digits and check for minlength validation
      zip.setValue('123');
      expect(zip.errors['minlength']).toBeTruthy();

      // enter 7 digits and check for maxlength validation
      zip.setValue('1234567');
      fixture.detectChanges(); // update changes, angular will not do for you automatically
      expect(zip.errors['maxlength']).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the test error

```
AppComponent
 ✖ form should be valid on entering required fields
   HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Linux 0.0.0)
  Expected false to be truthy.
    at UserContext. (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:35:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke 
 (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:358:1)
```

Comment: It's still not valid because you gave no values for street, city and zip?

Comment: thanks @Riscie for having a look, but i have no need to apply validations on street and city. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: I think `zip` is required, but you aren't providing it in the tests.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev that's not an issue brother
by the way all other things are provided by hackerrank,I had deal with app.component.html and app.component.ts files only

Comment: Your test ist failing because zip has no value, but a value is required. Either remove the validation for the zip property or provide a value for it within your tests. See my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test ist failing because zip has no value, but a value is required. Either remove the validation for the zip property or provide a value within your tests.

**Removing the validation for zip within AppComponent would look like this**

```
contactForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(null, [ Validators.required,
                                    Validators.minLength(4),
                                    Validators.maxLength(10)]),
        phone: new FormControl(null,  [ Validators.required,
                                        Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"),        Validators.minLength(10),
                                        Validators.maxLength(10) ]),
        address: new FormGroup({
        street: new FormControl(null),
        city: new FormControl(null),
        zip: new FormControl(null)
        })
    });
```

**Passing in a value for zip within your tests would look like this**

```
    it('form should be valid on entering required fields', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges(); // ngOninit()
        component.name.setValue('david');
        component.phone.setValue('9999999999');
        component.zip.setValue('123456');

        expect(component.contactForm.valid).toBeTruthy();
      });
```

The second option only works if you have setters for these properties in your component. In your stackblitz there are only getters.

Comment: yes, I got it now. Actually i don't need to apply **required validation** for zip. Thank you very much brother.

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code to `app.component.ts`:

```
contactForm = new FormGroup({

  name: new FormControl(null,[ 
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(4),
  Validators.maxLength(10)]),                        
  phone: new FormControl(null,[
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"),
  Validators.minLength(10),
  Validators.maxLength(10) ]),
                                        
  address: new FormGroup({
    street: new FormControl(null),
    city: new FormControl(null),
    zip: new FormControl(null,[ 
    Validators.minLength(6),
    Validators.maxLength(6),
    Validators.pattern('^[0-6]*$')])
    })
});
```

Comment: Just add this piece of code in your app.component.ts file. And the program will compile all your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check Your form is Valid or not, which means Empty or not, then you should use the. this.formData.valid();
In this method u get a response if your form is invalid then you get an error, otherwise, you will get true.